# Find the equation and height of an elliptical whispering room

Tags: conic-sections

The room is 150 feet long and the distance from the center of the room to the foci is 60 feet.

Finding $a^2$ is easy its 
$$2a=150$$
$$a=75$$
$$a^2=5625$$

but where I get lost is finding $b^2$, I know I shouldn't look at the answer before solving but I was stuck for 10 mins. trying to figure it out.

Anyway $b=45$ and I have no idea how to calucate that because what am I suppose to use the $60$ feet from the foci for?

I thought it was 
$$2b=60$$
$$b=30$$
$$b^2=900$$
but that doesn't work, then I thought it should be
$$2b=120$$
$$b=60$$
$$b^2=3600$$
and again I get stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this sketch

[image]

We know

- $BF_1+BF_2= AF_1+AF_2 = 2AO = 150$ as this is an ellipse with a fixed combined distance from the foci to a point on the edge
- and that $OF_1=OF_2=60$
- so $OA^2 =75^2$ as you found
- while $OB^2 = 75^2-60^2 = 45^2$ by Pythagoras

so the height (or width?) is  $2OB=90$

and the equation of the room might be $\dfrac{x^2}{75^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{45^2}=1$

Answer (score 1):

You can use $c^2=a^2-b^2$, so $b=\sqrt{a^2-c^2}=\sqrt{75^2-60^2}=15\sqrt{5^2-4^2}=15\cdot3=45$

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, just you need to know more about ellipse. In ellipse, the distance of centre from focus is $ae$, where $e=\sqrt{1-(\frac b a)^2}$. Now it is easy.

e is called eccentricity of the ellipse.